# Concept of sample mean and adding random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

The following came from Degroot's "Probability and Statistics" textbook.

Let $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ be random variables. The average of these $n$ random variables, $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, is called their sample mean.

My understanding is that each random variable, $X_i$, contains a set of random values and are not necessarily scalars unless the set size is 1. If this understanding is correct, then how can we be adding random variables together?

Comment: $X_i$ is not a set, it is a real-valued function of elementary event. The real-valued functions of the same argument can be added as real numbers.

Comment: @NCh. I do understand that definition, but I'm quite confused by some sites, such as https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/random-variables.html, defining a random variable to be a set. My guess is they mean the domain of the random variable is a set?

Comment: This is a bad notation only. They mean that if a coin flip head (elementary event $\omega=H$ appears), $X=X(H)=1$ and if tails ($\omega=T$) then $X=X(T)=0$. And yes, the domain of r.v. there is a set $\{0,1\}$ but it is not reasonable to identify r.v. with this set. If only the set of values is given, we do not know what elementary events correspond to this values and cannot operate with different r.v.'s. Exactly as you ask.